# How to link an external swagger json file to Python FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, swagger, fastapi

I have a swagger JSON file that I would like to link to my Python FastAPI script to replace the default `/docs` auto-generated one, any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why you should do this?

Comment: It's easier to create and edit the docs in the swagger editor rather than in the FastAPI script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this, but you can easily override/extend the `openapi` generation, by following [the documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi).

Here's a small code-sample on how to achieve the desired outcome:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import json

app = FastAPI()

def custom_openapi():
    with open("openapi.json", "r") as openapi:
        return json.load(openapi)

app.openapi = custom_openapi
```

The result:

[image: Custom OpenAPI]

Note though that keeping the documentation up-to-date and accurate using this method is going to be a pain, and you are throwing away a big chunk of `FastAPI`s feature set: I highly recommend against it.